# Styling <input type=“file”> CSS error

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to style an input button but a jQuery function seems to interfere.

HTML code:

```
<form action="../include/upload-local-file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imageuploadform">
<div class="uploaded" style="display:inline-block"></div>
<div class="formupload" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: -10px;"><input name="imagefile" id="file" type="file" class="uploadinput" /></div>
```

jQuery code:

```
function() {
$('#imageuploadform').submit();
}
```

My CSS code:

```
#imageuploadform input[type="file"] {
background : url("../images/selecteaza.png") no-repeat center center;
width: 186px;
height:40px;
border: none;
color: transparent;
font-size: 0 !important;
}
```

Unfortunately, I still have part of the original button visibile, both in FF and Chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWSQs.png

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you say that jQuery affects styling? Also, try changing border to `border: 0 none;`.

Comment: I changed the border setting, no change. I said the jQuery code affects the styling because the CSS code would work if the input button was inside the HTML code.

Comment: Not a duplicate. I read most threads on this subject, but none of them had the input button done by jQuery. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by _"... had the input button done by jQuery"_?

Comment: I mean I don't have a simple code like: <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />. I have $('#imageuploadform').submit();

Comment: Your js is invalid and will likely throw an error so I doubt that is the cause of your css issues (unless you style the file input using a js plugin)

Comment: @Alex that javascript has absolutely nothing to do with how your input is styled

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to style the input directly. As others have stated, this is not the way to do it. Look at the duplicate question.

Comment: see my minmal example below and alter `div class="formupload` to a `label` ... than add the css from the example and you're done

Comment: Thank you, guys, it totally worked. I changed the DIV to a LABEL like denns said, then applied the tutorial that Turnip recommended! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You normally hide the original button with css and wrap it with a label.

https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomFileInputs/

The label always triggers the original button even if not visible.

https://codepen.io/denns/pen/zRYZga here a minimal example

```
input[type="file"]{
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}


label {
  // whatever
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed hotpink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I read a few tutorials but I only know CSS, I don't know how to add the CSS code to the input in the jQuery function.

Comment: what do you mean by "add css in jquery function"? you can do something like:
`$('#mybutton').css({color: 'red'}).submit()`

Comment: why is this downvoted???